# Viewing previously run SELECT queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, audit

I'm looking at trying to see what Queries were run the past week. I can see all transaction type queries, however, when it comes to "Selects" I'm coming up lost as it's returning empty.

I've tried multiple queries and it's all blank for the dates I want. (I'm getting today, but not yesterday for example).

Are there any tools that can look into a SQL Server and dig out some historical queries?

Sample of queries I've run:

```
SELECT  dest.text, deqs.creation_time
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
order by deqs. asc
```

_

```
with s as (
select top(10000)
creation_time,
last_execution_time,
execution_count,
total_worker_time/1000 as CPU,
convert(money, (total_worker_time))/(execution_count*1000)as [AvgCPUTime],
qs.total_elapsed_time/1000 as TotDuration,
convert(money, (qs.total_elapsed_time))/(execution_count*1000)as [AvgDur],
total_logical_reads as [Reads],
total_logical_writes as [Writes],
total_logical_reads+total_logical_writes as [AggIO],
convert(money, (total_logical_reads+total_logical_writes)/(execution_count + 0.0)) as [AvgIO],
[sql_handle],
plan_handle,
statement_start_offset,
statement_end_offset,
plan_generation_num,
total_physical_reads,
convert(money, total_physical_reads/(execution_count + 0.0)) as [AvgIOPhysicalReads],
convert(money, total_logical_reads/(execution_count + 0.0)) as [AvgIOLogicalReads],
convert(money, total_logical_writes/(execution_count + 0.0)) as [AvgIOLogicalWrites],
query_hash,
query_plan_hash,
total_rows,
convert(money, total_rows/(execution_count + 0.0)) as [AvgRows],
total_dop,
convert(money, total_dop/(execution_count + 0.0)) as [AvgDop],
total_grant_kb,
convert(money, total_grant_kb/(execution_count + 0.0)) as [AvgGrantKb],
total_used_grant_kb,
convert(money, total_used_grant_kb/(execution_count + 0.0)) as [AvgUsedGrantKb],
total_ideal_grant_kb,
convert(money, total_ideal_grant_kb/(execution_count + 0.0)) as [AvgIdealGrantKb],
total_reserved_threads,
convert(money, total_reserved_threads/(execution_count + 0.0)) as [AvgReservedThreads],
total_used_threads,
convert(money, total_used_threads/(execution_count + 0.0)) as [AvgUsedThreads]
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats as qs with(readuncommitted)
order by convert(money, (qs.total_elapsed_time))/(execution_count*1000) desc
)
select
s.creation_time,
s.last_execution_time,
s.execution_count,
s.CPU,
s.[AvgCPUTime],
s.TotDuration,
s.[AvgDur],
s.[AvgIOLogicalReads],
s.[AvgIOLogicalWrites],
s.[AggIO],
s.[AvgIO],
s.[AvgIOPhysicalReads],
s.plan_generation_num,
s.[AvgRows],
s.[AvgDop],
s.[AvgGrantKb],
s.[AvgUsedGrantKb],
s.[AvgIdealGrantKb],
s.[AvgReservedThreads],
s.[AvgUsedThreads],
--st.text as query_text,
case
when sql_handle IS NULL then ' '
else(substring(st.text,(s.statement_start_offset+2)/2,(
case
when s.statement_end_offset =-1 then len(convert(nvarchar(MAX),st.text))*2      
else s.statement_end_offset    
end - s.statement_start_offset)/2  ))
end as query_text,
db_name(st.dbid) as database_name,
object_schema_name(st.objectid, st.dbid)+'.'+object_name(st.objectid, st.dbid) as [object_name],
sp.[query_plan],
s.[sql_handle],
s.plan_handle,
s.query_hash,
s.query_plan_hash
from s
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s.[sql_handle]) as st
cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(s.[plan_handle]) as sp
```